# why is the complexity O(n^2)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, pseudocode

```
function F(A :Array){
    i=1
    j=1
    m=0
    c=0
    while i<=Size(A) do
        if A[i]=A[j] then
            c=c+1
        end if
        j=j+1
        if j>Size(A) then
            if c>m then
                m=c
            end if
            c=0
            i=i+1
            j=i
        end if
    end while
return m
```

I found the first O(n) but can't find the second to they can be O(n^2)
thank you for your help

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roughly. In the loop `j` varies first from `i` to size of `A`. Each time `j`  reaches the end `i` is incremented.
Say that `n` is size of `A`, you first loop (roughly, don't want to analyse exactly, no need) `n` times, then `n-1`, etc. Thus n+n-1+n-2+n-3+...+1, which is n(n+1)2 thus a square of `n`.